# What do Haikus in Ghost of Tsushima do and how do they work?

Tags: ghost-of-tsushima

There are places in the world where you can compose Haikus. I've done that three times now, and the only result seems to be a headband received for each. Those seem to be purely cosmetic items.

Does it matter how you compose the Haiku? Are all results the same, or is there a "correct" choice?

Answer (score 6):

There is a trophy for doing all the Haiku sites (you also need to visit various other sites):

> "Body, Mind, and Spirit" visit all Hot Springs, Haiku, Inari Shrines, and Bamboo Strikes

Other than that I think these are just intended to be a moment of reflection amid all the fighting.

There doesn't seem to be a correct choice, and the headbands (and other hats) are just cosmetic.

Answer (score 3):

*Just the theme counts here.*
*It will determine the look.*
*Your choice sets the text.*

(I'm horrible at Haikus, so, yes, they won’t change visually, but the game remembers your choice for the flavor text. There’s no wrong or right.)

Comment: Well it IS a haiku. Bravo!